# why does content-type header get removed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, visual-studio-2017, postman

I am issuing a request like so:

[image]

And when inspecting what has been sent to my controller, it looks like the **Content-Type** header does not even make it there:

[image]

**What am I doing wrong? Why is Content-Type header being ignored completely?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit confusing, but Content-Type headers are not accessible from the generic "Headers" collection.

You should actually pull the header from the [ContentType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httpcontentheaders.contenttype(v=vs.118).aspx) property of the Headers object on the content object of the request:

```
var contentType = Request.Content.Headers.ContentType;
```

Comment: how would you add contenttype header to a new request?